# Including lagged differences - time series

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, lags

- List item

[image]

Why would the researcher include the additional lagged differences in the second equation? Don't need a full solution, just a tip.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: looks like home work to me, see self-study tag rules

Comment: Hi, Aksakal! You are somehow right, it is not part of a homework, but rather a subpoint from a past paper exercise. Am I not allowed to post such things? I will delete it, if not.I was thinking it is not like a whole problem and that this could maybe also help others. Again, sorry if this is not ok. I am new on the website.

Comment: you can ask anything, of course. if it's not a current home work, then no need for self-study tag